# How to create custom option menu in android

Tags: android, android-menu

I am creating an option menu. it has three option HOME, EMAIL, VISIT. All three options coming at the same row. i have to show HOME option above and rest two below to Home Option(according to attached Screen Shot).

Any Ideas??
Thanks.

[image]

Here is my XML file.

```
<menu android:id="@+id/new_game"
          android:icon="@drawable/red_no_bg"
          android:title="Home" />
    <item android:id="@+id/email"
          android:icon="@drawable/red_no_bg"
          android:title="Email" />
    <item android:id="@+id/help"
          android:icon="@drawable/red_no_bg"
          android:title="Visit Microsite" />
</menu>
```

Here is my code.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.overview_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Using the above code i am getting the all option in Same line.

Answer (score 2):

You can Create in two ways

1.Statically.

2.Dynamically.

Am explaining the easiest method of adding menus.

Step 1: Create a new Android Application.

Step 2: After `onCreate()` method write `onCreateOptionMenu();`

Step 3: In `onCreateOptionMenu()` Write these lines

`menu.add(11, 21, 1, "Gowtham").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);`

Here "Gowtham" is title of your menu item You can `Home`&`Email` use instead of "Gowtham".

Ans use Any images Instead of `ic.launcher`